# python regular expression to match six digit number from a string with multiple delimiters

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I wanted to find all the six digit numbers with multiple delimited comma,Hyphen and  space but not under score.

For example:

```
string = "OS 2.2.0_cvr_test_648052_02 & v1.2.1_ab1_03, xyz-800239,test-434523,456345 902384"
```

Required Output: `[800239,434523,456345,902384]`.

The output should not include six digit number with "underscore". From the above string the number "648052" should not be printed.

Could you please help me finding the better solution?

I have re as `re.findall('[-, ][0-9]{6}', string)` But it prints the delimiters too.

Comment: try `(?<=[-, ])[0-9]{6}`

Comment: Awesome!! It works> Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lookbehind:

```
import re
string = "OS 2.2.0_cvr_test_648052_02 & v1.2.1_ab1_03, xyz-800239,test-434523,456345 902384"
new_string = list(map(int, re.findall('(?<=[^_])\d{6}', string)))
```

Output:

```
[800239, 434523, 456345, 902384]
```

Comment: That doesn't match the delimiters that OP specified. The method isn't wrong, but the result is. [See here](https://regex101.com/r/HoW62p/3)

Comment: @emsimpson92 The output above does match the OP's desired output (`[800239,434523,456345,902384]`). Can you clarify?

Comment: It matches the one example he provided, but who knows what the rest of the input might look like. [It's pretty easy to break it if he uses some slightly different input.](https://regex101.com/r/HoW62p/3)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work `(?<=[-, ]|^)\d{6}(?=[-, ]|$)`

https://regex101.com/r/BtOfJ5/1